# Why does the following Go program need the function's name to be String() and not anything else?

Tags: go

I'm following a book which shows the following example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    KB = 1024
    MB = 1048576          //KB * 1024
    GB = 1073741824       //MB * 1024
    TB = 1099511627776    //GB * 1024
    PB = 1125899906842624 //TB * 1024
)

type ByteSize float64

func (b ByteSize) String() string {
    switch {
    case b >= PB:
        return "Very Big"
    case b >= TB:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%.2fTB", b/TB)
    case b >= GB:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%.2fGB", b/GB)
    case b >= MB:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%.2fMB", b/MB)
    case b >= KB:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%.2fKB", b/KB)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%dB", b)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ByteSize(2048))
    fmt.Println(ByteSize(3292528.64))
}
```

When I run this program it gives me the following output (in human readable data size units).

```
2.00KB
3.14MB
```

But when I change the name of the function called String() to anything else, or if I lower-case the S in String, it gives me the following output.

```
2048
3.29252864e+06
```

What is the reason behind that? Is there some String() function attached to some interface and our ByteSize type satisfies that interface? I mean what the hell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a method named `String` with no parameters returning a string, you implement the `Stringer` interface, which is documented here: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer.

Comment: Not true. Not only must the function name match, but the functions signature.

Comment: Might be a bit strong to say "not true", it's necessary but not sufficient. Clarified.

Comment: `func (t *T)String()` != `func(t *T)String() string`. For you and me, that might be obvious - for others it might not be. Hence my rather strong objection ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your last sentence is exactly right. In Go, you can satisfy interfaces you didn't even know existed. And you can write new interfaces for other people's functions. Their code does not have to write "implement" or derive or anything. It is entirely based on the function name and having a matching argument and return value list.

Answer (score 1):

The example is very similar to an example in "Effective Go" by the Go Authors, and the meaning of the `String()` method described there.

> The ability to attach a method such as String to any user-defined type
>   makes it possible for arbitrary values to format themselves
>   automatically for printing. Although you'll see it most often applied
>   to structs, this technique is also useful for scalar types such as
>   floating-point types like ByteSize.

See: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants